# getting the cancel event of Java ProgressMonitor

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, progressmonitor

I have a ProgressMonitor `pm` and a SwingWorker `sw`. I want to cancel the SwingWorker when I press the `cancel`-button on `pm`. I guess this shouldnt be too hard, and I read some tutorials about SwingWorker and ProgressMonitor, but I can't get this to work.

```
final ProgressMonitor pm = new ProgressMonitor(frame, "checking", "...", 0, 100);
final SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker()
{
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception 
    {
        doSomethingAndUpdateProgress();
    }
};

sw.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener()
{
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
    {
        if(evt.getPropertyName().equals("progress"))
        {
            updateProgress();
        }
        if(pm.isCanceled())
        {
            cancelAction();
        }
        if(pm.isDone())
        {
            doneAction();
        }
    }
});

sw.execute();
```

Progress updating is working just fine, but `pm.isCanceled()` is never `true`. I suppose I need a propertyChangeListener for the ProgressMonitor, but I dont know how I would add one there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the execution of your long running task, you want to periodically check if the `ProgressMonitor` was canceled.  It's your job to check that at points where it makes sense to cancel the task - otherwise who knows what resources you could leave hanging.

So basically, you want to change your `doSomethingAndUpdateProgress()` method so that it also checks if the `ProgressMonitor` was canceled.

Here's a demo that shows how this works:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TempProject extends Box{

    public TempProject(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        final ProgressMonitor pm = new ProgressMonitor(this, "checking", "...", 0, 100);
        final SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker<Integer, Integer>()
        {
            protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception 
            {
                int i = 0;
                //While still doing work and progress  monitor wasn't canceled
                 while (i++ < 100 && !pm.isCanceled()) {
                     System.out.println(i);
                     publish(i);
                     Thread.sleep(100);
                 }
                 return null;
            }


             @Override
             protected void process(java.util.List<Integer> chunks) {
                 for (int number : chunks) {
                     pm.setProgress(number);
                 }
             }

        };

        sw.execute();
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                frame.setContentPane(new TempProject());    
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }   


}
```

Comment: Allthough mKorbel's answer was very informative it lacked the ProgressMonitor I was actually asking about - so I chose this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

> and I read some tutorials about SwingWorker and ProgressMonitor, but I can't get this to work.

canceling always invoked an InteruptedExeption,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SwingWorkerExample extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final JButton startButton, stopButton;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    private JList listBox = null;
    private DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    private final JProgressBar progressBar;
    private mySwingWorker swingWorker;

    public SwingWorkerExample() {
        super("SwingWorkerExample");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        startButton = makeButton("Start");
        stopButton = makeButton("Stop");
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        progressBar = makeProgressBar(0, 99);
        listBox = new JList(listModel);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(listBox);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        //Display the window.
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
//Class SwingWorker<T,V> T - the result type returned by this SwingWorker's doInBackground
//and get methods V - the type used for carrying out intermediate results by this SwingWorker's
//publish and process methods

    private class mySwingWorker extends javax.swing.SwingWorker<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer> {
//The first template argument, in this case, ArrayList<Integer>, is what s returned by doInBackground(),
//and by get(). The second template argument, in this case, Integer, is what is published with the
//publish method. It is also the data type which is stored by the java.util.List that is the parameter
//for the process method, which recieves the information published by the publish method.

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Integer> doInBackground() {
//Returns items of the type given as the first template argument to the SwingWorker class.
            if (javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
                System.out.println("javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() returned true.");
            }
            Integer tmpValue = new Integer(1);
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) { //find every 100th prime, just to make it slower
                    tmpValue = FindNextPrime(tmpValue.intValue());
//isCancelled() returns true if the cancel() method is invoked on this class. That is the proper way
//to stop this thread. See the actionPerformed method.
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        System.out.println("SwingWorker - isCancelled");
                        return list;
                    }
                }
//Successive calls to publish are coalesced into a java.util.List, which is what is received by process,
//which in this case, isused to update the JProgressBar. Thus, the values passed to publish range from
//1 to 100.
                publish(new Integer(i));
                list.add(tmpValue);
            }
            return list;
        }//Note, always use java.util.List here, or it will use the wrong list.

        @Override
        protected void process(java.util.List<Integer> progressList) {
//This method is processing a java.util.List of items given as successive arguments to the publish method.
//Note that these calls are coalesced into a java.util.List. This list holds items of the type given as the
//second template parameter type to SwingWorker. Note that the get method below has nothing to do with the
//SwingWorker get method; it is the List's get method. This would be a good place to update a progress bar.
            if (!javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
                System.out.println("javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() + returned false.");
            }
            Integer percentComplete = progressList.get(progressList.size() - 1);
            progressBar.setValue(percentComplete.intValue());
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            System.out.println("doInBackground is complete");
            if (!javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
                System.out.println("javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() + returned false.");
            }
            try {
//Here, the SwingWorker's get method returns an item of the same type as specified as the first type parameter
//given to the SwingWorker class.
                ArrayList<Integer> results = get();
                for (Integer i : results) {
                    listModel.addElement(i.toString());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Caught an exception: " + e);
            }
            startButton();
        }

        boolean IsPrime(int num) { //Checks whether a number is prime
            int i;
            for (i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
                if (num % i == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected Integer FindNextPrime(int num) { //Returns next prime number from passed arg.
            do {
                if (num % 2 == 0) {
                    num++;
                } else {
                    num += 2;
                }
            } while (!IsPrime(num));
            return new Integer(num);
        }
    }

    private class TaskListener implements PropertyChangeListener {

        private String name;

        TaskListener(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
            System.out.println(name + ": "
                    + e.getOldValue() + " -> " + e.getNewValue());
        }
    }

    private JButton makeButton(String caption) {
        JButton b = new JButton(caption);
        b.setActionCommand(caption);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(b);
        return b;
    }

    private JProgressBar makeProgressBar(int min, int max) {
        JProgressBar progressBar1 = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar1.setMinimum(min);
        progressBar1.setMaximum(max);
        progressBar1.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar1.setBorderPainted(true);
        getContentPane().add(progressBar1);
        return progressBar1;
    }

    private void startButton() {
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        System.out.println("SwingWorker - Done");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("Start" == null ? e.getActionCommand() == null : "Start".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            startButton.setEnabled(false);
            stopButton.setEnabled(true);
// Note that it creates a new instance of the SwingWorker-derived class. Never reuse an old one.
            (swingWorker = new mySwingWorker()).execute(); // new instance
            swingWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new TaskListener("Task"));

        } else if ("Stop" == null ? e.getActionCommand() == null : "Stop".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            startButton.setEnabled(true);
            stopButton.setEnabled(false);
            swingWorker.cancel(true); // causes isCancelled to return true in doInBackground
            swingWorker = null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// Notice that it kicks it off on the event-dispatching thread, not the main thread.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SwingWorkerExample swingWorkerExample = new SwingWorkerExample();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andrew Thompson these comments are by `aterai` or `darryl` to my question from `sun.forum.57`